# How to abbreviate/truncate the value of every key?

Tags: jq

I have a JSON like:

```json
{
  "a": "hi",
  "b": 4213,
  "c": 23154646789132456,
  "d": "a very long string that should be shortened",
  "e": {
    "x": "some value",
    "y": {
      "alpha": "foo"
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to use jq to "abbreviate" values longer than `n` characters. Each value should be converted to a string `s`, and if the result is longer than `n`, it should be replaced with `s[:n] + " ..."`. If the string is not too long, it should ideally be left as the original value. I expect a result like:

```json
# n=5
{
  "a": "hi",
  "b": 4213,  # "4213" would be acceptable too, but not preferable
  "c": "23154 ...",
  "d" : "a ver ...,
  "e" : "{\n\"x\" ..."  # I don't care how whitespace is handled
}
# yes, I know there's no comments in JSON :)
```

The idea is to have something like "folding" when looking at complex objects, so that I can get an overview of what top level keys are there, and then decide which key I want to "zoom in" to (eg `jq '.e'`).

In Python I could do something like:

```
j = load_my_json()
for k in j:
    s = str(j[k])
    if len(s) > n:
       j[k] = f"{s[:10]}..."
```

But how can I do it in jq?

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error, I came up with:

```
$ cat j.json | jq 'to_entries | map({(.key): (.value | tostring[:20] + " ...")})' | jq -s '.[] | add'
{
  "a": "shortval",
  "b": "4213",
  "c": "23154646789132456",
  "d": "a very long string t",
  "e": "{\"x\":\"some value\",\"y"
}
```

Which is what I want. This seems a bit inelegant, especially having to do the `-s` call, but it's good enough for what I'm doing. I'll leave the question unanswered in case someone has a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

In the simplest case, we convert each item using `tostring` and check the string's `length`

```
$ jq --argjson n 10 '.[] |= (
  tostring | if length > $n then .[:$n] + "..." else . end
)' j.json
{
  "a": "hi",
  "b": "4213",
  "c": "2315464678...",
  "d": "a very lon...",
  "e": "{\"x\":\"some..."
}
```

To prevent the numbers from being converted to strings, we can wrap the simple case with another `if` condition checking the item's `type`

```
$ jq --argjson n 10 '.[] |= (
  if type == "number" then . else
    tostring | if length > $n then .[:$n] + "..." else . end
  end
)' j.json
{
  "a": "hi",
  "b": 4213,
  "c": 23154646789132456,
  "d": "a very lon...",
  "e": "{\"x\":\"some..."
}
```

Finally, if we want to keep the numbers as numbers if and only if their string representation matches the length criteria, we serialize both conditions with both applying `tostring` once for conversion and once for testing:

```
$ jq --argjson n 10 '.[] |= (
  if type == "number" then . else tostring end
  | if tostring | length > $n then tostring | .[:$n] + "..." else . end
)' j.json
{
  "a": "hi",
  "b": 4213,
  "c": "2315464678...",
  "d": "a very lon...",
  "e": "{\"x\":\"some..."
}
```

Comment: The last program above calls tostring twice or three times, whereas only once is necessary: `.[] |= (
  tostring as $s
  | if type == "number" then . else $s end
  | if $s | length > $n then $s[:$n] + "..." else . end)`